# How often should an application perform a fetch request? numberOfRowsInSection returns incorrect (predicate does not change, cache is nil)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**Update 2** So I've fixed the problem by putting the fetch request that was originally inside the segment changed `IBAction`, and instead the `viewDidLoad` function. I'm still not sure why this works exactly. Is an application only suppposed to perform a fetch request once and then just update/reload the data?

**Update:** I've made several changes to my code (which I will add below). With these changes, the new scenario is that **if I go to the view controller with the two tables (where now the first, static table is only visible) and then display the second table and then switch back to the first table, and then go to a different tab and add an object to my core data - my app crashes** with:

> attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update
>   (null)

I can recreate it every time. At this point, I'm trying to see if the bug must has something to do  with my `segmentChanged` method/how I set up my fetched result controllers.

===========================================================================

I inherited a pretty old iOS project. I have a view controller with a segmented control that controls which of two UITables a user sees. When you switch between indexes of the segmented control, a different table (with a diff fetch request) reloads data. One UITable (segment index 1) allows users to add and remove rows. I set the table's delegate and data source in the Storyboard and also in viewDidLoad.

Occasionally when a user inserts a new object in core data (and thus a new row in the table), I get an `invalid update` error. It doesn't happen all the time, but when it does, its because the number returned by numberOfRowsInSection does not reflect the newly inserted row. It makes sense that this would happen if the object hasn't been saved to core data yet, which I *think* is because of threading?

I'm still trying to understand threading... I set breakpoints to figure out the order of the application. When I insert a new object, `uploadImage` is called and creates the ASIFormDataRequest, executed in the main queue. Then `startAsynchronous` gets called, which starts the main function in the `ASIHTTPRequest` class (to create and start the HTTPRequest). Then `requestFinished` is called (for instance, it doesn't arrive at `[delegate leafletPhotoUploader:self didUploadImage:collectedLeaf];`), but before that code finishes, `didChangeObject` is called with case `ChangeInsert`. This fires `numberOfRowsInSection`. Sometimes the number returned in this function is correct, but other times its not. If its not accounting for the newly inserted row, the app crashes at `[_table endUpdates]` in `controllerDidChangeContent`.

I looked at other posts similar to mine, but [I don't change the predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592292/core-data-does-not-react-on-changed-predicate), [I set the cache to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420155/coredata-numberofobjects-in-section-incorrect?rq=1) when I create the fetch controller and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446758/why-nsfetchedresultscontroller-is-not-being-updated-with-new-data) suggests its an Apple bug.

**Why is `numberOfRowsInSection` returning an incorrect amount - sometimes but not always?**

Segmented Control to hide/display tables:

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender {

    //first table: Database
    if (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        /*for switching between collection map view and browse list */
        [_userCollectionTable setHidden:YES];
        [_databasetable setHidden:NO];
        _databasetable.delegate = self;
        _databasetable.dataSource = self;

        [mapVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [mapVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        [_mapVC removeFromParentViewController];

        _searchController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
        if (storedDataset_ != dataset) {
            speciesCurrentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataset & %d > 0", dataset];
        }

        [self fetchResultsUsingSegmentedControlIndex];

        if (currentSelectedIndexPath)
        {
            [[self.databasetable cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedIndexPath] setSelected:NO animated:YES];
            currentSelectedIndexPath = nil;
        }

        [_databasetable reloadData];

        // Define your required task...
    }
    /*second "tab" - My Collection
     set up table view of user's collected leafs*/
    else if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [_userCollectionTable setHidden:NO];
        [_databasetable setHidden:YES];

        _userCollectionTable.delegate = self;
        _userCollectionTable.dataSource = self;

        NSError *error;
        [self collectionFetchedResultsController:collectionCurrentPredicate];
        [self.collectionFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        collectedLeafArray = [collectionFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
        [_userCollectionTable reloadData];
    }


}
```

Where I set my fetched results controller

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)collectionFetchedResultsController:(NSPredicate*)predicate
    {
    NSString * sectionNameKeyPath = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [(LeafletAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    // Create and configure a fetch request with the Species entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"this a predicate %@", predicate);
    if(predicate){
        sectionNameKeyPath = @"collectedDate";
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CollectedLeaf" inManagedObjectContext:context] ;
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create the sort descriptors array.
    NSSortDescriptor *idDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"collectedDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:idDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
    collectionFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:nil];
    collectionFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    // Memory management.
    [fetchRequest release];
    [idDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return collectionFetchedResultsController;
}
```

Where I create the ASIFormDataRequest request:

```
- (void)uploadImage
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* serverURL = kDefaultSearchServer;

    // setting up the URL to post to
    NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/upload/?fmt=json", serverURL];

    NSLog(@"Start upload to %@", stringURL);

    leafRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];

    [leafRequest setPostValue:[defaults stringForKey:@"user_name"] forKey:@"user"];
    [leafRequest setPostValue:[defaults stringForKey:@"user_password"] forKey:@"passwd"];
    [leafRequest setPostValue:collectedLeaf.latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
    [leafRequest setPostValue:collectedLeaf.longitude forKey:@"longitude"];
    [leafRequest setPostValue:collectedLeaf.altitude forKey:@"altitude"];
    [leafRequest setPostValue:collectedLeaf.userDataset forKey:@"user_dataset"];
    [leafRequest setData:imageData withFileName:@"iphonefile.jpg" andContentType:@"application/octet-stream" forKey:@"myfile"];
    [leafRequest setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
    [leafRequest buildPostBody];
    [leafRequest setDelegate:self];
    [leafRequest startAsynchronous];
    });
}
```

Where I save to core data **(updated)**

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    //NSLog(@"Photo uploader response: %@", responseString);
    // Use when fetching binary data
    //NSData *responseData = [request responseData];

    NSError *error;
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"Photo uploader response: %@", jsonDictionary);

    if (jsonDictionary == nil)
    {

        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kLeafletErrorDomain code:kErrorResultNotReady userInfo:nil];
        if(![self isALabelRequest:request] && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletPhotoUploader:didFailWithError:)])
        {
            [delegate leafletPhotoUploader:self didFailWithError:error];
        }
    }

    else if (collectedLeaf)
    {
        // If this is the first time uploading
        if(collectedLeaf.leafID == nil) {
            //NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(LeafletAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
            NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = collectedLeaf.managedObjectContext;
            [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{

                collectedLeaf.leafID = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
                LeafletURL* segmentedImageURL = (LeafletURL*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LeafletURL" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                segmentedImageURL.dataSource = @"SegmentedImage";
                segmentedImageURL.type = @"SegmentedImage";
                segmentedImageURL.rawURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/segmented.png", collectedLeaf.leafID];
                segmentedImageURL.hiResImageLocation = kLocationServer;
                segmentedImageURL.thumbnailLocation = kLocationServer;
                collectedLeaf.segmentedImageURL = segmentedImageURL;
                LeafletURL* originalImageURL = (LeafletURL*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LeafletURL" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                originalImageURL.dataSource = @"OriginalImage";
                originalImageURL.type = @"OriginalImage";
                originalImageURL.rawURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/original.jpg", collectedLeaf.leafID];
                originalImageURL.hiResImageLocation = kLocationServer;
                originalImageURL.thumbnailLocation = kLocationServer;
                collectedLeaf.originalImageURL = originalImageURL;
                NSLog(@"collectedleaf: %@", collectedLeaf);
                NSError *error = nil;
                BOOL success = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
                if(!success){
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error saving %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    [self showAlert];
                }
                else{
                    /*If successfully saved uploaded leaf, delete image stored in documents directory from collecting w/o internet connection */
                    if(collectedLeaf.localImageFileName){
                        [self removeImage:collectedLeaf.localImageFileName];
                    }
                }
            }];

        } else {
            // This means that the labeling has changed
            NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(LeafletAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
            collectedLeaf.syncStatus = kSyncStatusSame;
            [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        }
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    if(![self isALabelRequest:request] && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletPhotoUploader:didUploadImage:)])
    {
        [delegate leafletPhotoUploader:self didUploadImage:collectedLeaf];
    }
}
```

Starts asynchronous http request?

```
- (void)startAsynchronous
{
    NSLog(@"start asynchronous called here");
#if DEBUG_REQUEST_STATUS || DEBUG_THROTTLING
    NSLog(@"Starting asynchronous request %@",self);
#endif
    [sharedQueue addOperation:self];
}

- (void)main
{
    @try {

        [[self cancelledLock] lock];

        // A HEAD request generated by an ASINetworkQueue may have set the error already. If so, we should not proceed.
        if ([self error]) {
            [self setComplete:YES];
            [self markAsFinished];
            return;     
        }

        [self setComplete:NO];

        if (![self url]) {
            [self failWithError:ASIUnableToCreateRequestError];
            return;     
        }

        // Must call before we create the request so that the request method can be set if needs be
        if (![self mainRequest]) {
            [self buildPostBody];
        }

        if (![[self requestMethod] isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
            [self setDownloadCache:nil];
        }


        // If we're redirecting, we'll already have a CFHTTPMessageRef
        if (request) {
            CFRelease(request);
        }

        // Create a new HTTP request.
        request = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)[self requestMethod], (CFURLRef)[self url], [self useHTTPVersionOne] ? kCFHTTPVersion1_0 : kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
        if (!request) {
            [self failWithError:ASIUnableToCreateRequestError];
            return;
        }

        //If this is a HEAD request generated by an ASINetworkQueue, we need to let the main request generate its headers first so we can use them
        if ([self mainRequest]) {
            [[self mainRequest] buildRequestHeaders];
        }

        // Even if this is a HEAD request with a mainRequest, we still need to call to give subclasses a chance to add their own to HEAD requests (ASIS3Request does this)
        [self buildRequestHeaders];

        if ([self downloadCache]) {
            if ([self cachePolicy] == ASIDefaultCachePolicy) {
                [self setCachePolicy:[[self downloadCache] defaultCachePolicy]];
            }

            // See if we should pull from the cache rather than fetching the data
            if ([self cachePolicy] == ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy) {
                if ([self useDataFromCache]) {
                    return;
                }
            } else if ([self cachePolicy] == ASIReloadIfDifferentCachePolicy) {

                // Force a conditional GET if we have a cached version of this content already
                NSDictionary *cachedHeaders = [[self downloadCache] cachedHeadersForRequest:self];
                if (cachedHeaders) {
                    NSString *etag = [cachedHeaders objectForKey:@"Etag"];
                    if (etag) {
                        [[self requestHeaders] setObject:etag forKey:@"If-None-Match"];
                    }
                    NSString *lastModified = [cachedHeaders objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
                    if (lastModified) {
                        [[self requestHeaders] setObject:lastModified forKey:@"If-Modified-Since"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [self applyAuthorizationHeader];


        NSString *header;
        for (header in [self requestHeaders]) {
            CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(request, (CFStringRef)header, (CFStringRef)[[self requestHeaders] objectForKey:header]);
        }

        [self startRequest];

    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSError *underlyingError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASIUnhandledExceptionError userInfo:[exception userInfo]];
        [self failWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASIUnhandledExceptionError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[exception name],NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,[exception reason],NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey,underlyingError,NSUnderlyingErrorKey,nil]]];

    } @finally {
        [[self cancelledLock] unlock];
    }
}
```

Update the table view:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"ns fetched results change insert at %@", [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]);
            [_userCollectionTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            NSLog(@"ns fetched results change delete");
            [_userCollectionTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            NSLog(@"ns fetched results change update");
            [self configureCell:[_userCollectionTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [_userCollectionTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [_userCollectionTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }

}
```

numberOfRowsInSection, the tableview is for the user collection:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView == _databasetable){
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[speciesFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

    if(tableView == _userCollectionTable){
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[collectionFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        if([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] == 0){
            UILabel *noDataLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height)];
            noDataLabel.text             = @"Press the Snap It! tab to start collecting!";
            noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor whiteColor];
            noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel;
            tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            return 0;
        }else{
            sectionInfo = [[collectionFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
            tableView.backgroundView = nil;
            return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

managed object context getter override in `appDelegate` (**updated**)

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    NSThread *thisThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    if (thisThread == [NSThread mainThread])
    {
        //For the Main thread just return default context iVar
         if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
             return managedObjectContext;
         }

         NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
         if (coordinator != nil) {
             managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
             [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
         }
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    else
    {
        //Return separate MOC for each new thread
        NSManagedObjectContext * threadManagedObjectContext = [[thisThread threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"MOC_KEY"];
        if (threadManagedObjectContext == nil)
        {
            threadManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
                                          [threadManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
                                          [[thisThread threadDictionary] setObject:threadManagedObjectContext forKey:@"MOC_KEY"];

                                          }

            return threadManagedObjectContext;
                                          }
}
```

Comment: Could you place a breakpoint at `requestFinished` and verify that it's on the main thread?

Comment: Please share the code you use to update the tableview.  If it is an old project and you just want it to work you can just call reloadData in controllerDidChangeContent. It won't animate - but it will never break

Comment: @bauerMusic I just checked, and `requestFinished` is on the main thread

Comment: @JonRose thanks for the reminder to post that! I update the tableview in `didChangeContent`

Comment: It's impossible to say why your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns an incorrect value unless you include the code for that method. It could be doing anything, we have no way to know.

Comment: @TomHarrington updates with that method.

Comment: @bauerMusic I'm wondering if its an issue of a persistent NSManagedObjectContext, rather than creating a new one for each thread? Because though `requestFinished` is on the main thread, the `ASIHTTPRequest` is not ?

Comment: This might be unrelated, but you have a mismatch between your FRC sort descriptor ("collectedDate") and the sectionNameKeyPath ("selectedSpecies").  The two must be consistent.

Comment: @pbasdf I just tried matching the sort descriptor with the sectionNameKeyPath, but same bug. Thanks for identifying this other bug tho!

Comment: Where does the ManagedObjectContexts get merged? It is in a notification function? I recall having issues where another framework was using same function, resulting with having to identify 'our' context.

Comment: @bauerMusic ah! it appears no one implemented merging of MOC. Should I try to implement? Or leave as is (I removed the fetch request inside segmentChanged and it now works)

Comment: @bauerMusic I also previously only had a single MOC that I passed between threads. I changed it so that I create a new one for every thread, but that didnt solve the bug. Makes me wonder if implementing merging is necessary?